# Как сделать двустороннюю анимацию?

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, css-animation

На кружке ниже я сделал анимацию и добавляю ему класс при клике, но при повторном клике я хочу чтобы он обратно плавно возвращался в исходную позицию, а он просто резко встаёт в исходную позицию. Как сделать плавное возвращение назад?

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
circle.addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('circle-animate')
})
```

```css
@keyframes circle-animate {
  0% {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  50% {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 3px #000;
}

.circle-animate {
  animation-name: circle-animate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">Кликни на меня</div>
```

ЗЫ: Сделал чтото подобное( https://jsfiddle.net/bpw36tnL/58/ ), но думаю это костыли и есть баг - если кликнуть по середине анимации она прервётся и кружок перейдёт в исходное состояние другой анимации. Не красиво

Answer (score 5):

Можно пойти другим путём - если анимация несложная (как в данном вопросе), то использовать `transition` вместо `animation`. Выполняется главное условие - реверс с места клика, но...

Есть одна большая проблема - замирание анимации после клика, в ожидании окончания задержек, которые нужны для правильного порядка шагов. Если это не критично или анимации короткие, то попробуйте вариант ниже:

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
circle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('reverse');
});
```

```css
body { background-color: gray; }

.circle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 90px; width: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 3px #000;
  user-select: none;
  margin: 0;
  transition: margin-left 1s linear .5s, margin-top .5s linear;
}

.circle.reverse {
  margin-left: 200px; margin-top: 50px;
  transition: margin-left 1s linear, margin-top .5s linear 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">Кликни на меня</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант слушать события начала и конца анимации. Примерно вот так:

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
let direction = "forward";
let isAnimationEnd = true;

circle.addEventListener('animationstart', () => {
  isAnimationEnd = false;
});

circle.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  isAnimationEnd = true;
});


circle.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (isAnimationEnd && direction === "forward") {
    this.classList.remove('circle-animate-out');
    this.classList.add('circle-animate-in');
    direction = "back";
  }  
  else if (isAnimationEnd && direction === "back") {
    this.classList.remove('circle-animate-in');
    this.classList.add('circle-animate-out');
    direction = "forward";
  }
})
```

```css
@keyframes circle-animate-in {
  0% {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  50% {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes circle-animate-out {
  0% {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  
  50% {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 3px #000;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.circle-animate-in {
  transition: .3s ease;
  animation-name: circle-animate-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.circle-animate-out {
  transition: .3s ease;
  animation-name: circle-animate-out;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">Кликни на меня</div>
```

Comment: Делал. Нужно чтобы можно было остановить посередине анимации и чтобы она проигрывалась обратно

Comment: @Александр Д. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Comment: @PavelNazarian но как отловить место в котором нужно остановить анимацию при клике, когда она уже идёт, и именно с этого места запустить её обратно? Мне тут уже самому интересно стало.

Comment: @Макс к: _"... отловить место..."_ - в смысле позицию left/top ?

Comment: @UModeL как отловить left/top кажется понимаю. Но как в этом месте остановить анимацию если она уже началась?

Comment: @Макск: остановить не проблема - `animation-play-state: paused;`. Проблема - отследить/получить сам прогресс анимации. Ну и как-то эти прогрессом воспользоваться для анимации с реверсом.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
circle.addEventListener('click', function() {       
  if (this.classList.contains('circle-animate-forward')){       
    this.className = 'circle circle-animate-back deactive'      
    return
  } else {    
    this.className = 'circle circle-animate-forward deactive'            
    return
  }    
})
circle.addEventListener('animationend',function(){
  this.classList.remove('deactive')
})
```

```css
@keyframes circle-animate-forward {
  0% {
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  50% {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes circle-animate-back {
  0% {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  
  50% {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  to {
   margin: 0;
  }
}

.circle {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px 3px #000;
}


.circle.deactive{
  pointer-events: none;
}

.circle-animate-forward {
  animation-name: circle-animate-forward;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.circle-animate-back {
  animation-name: circle-animate-back;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">Кликни на меня</div>
```